# Adding a character to empty row

Tags: php, mysql

My database contains empty table columns.
I would like to add a character like § to these empty rows so that I can search for them easier. How would I go about?

I already have a script that lets me replace or remove characters but I dont know a way to specify that rows that are empty should be updated with a character.

Comment: is it like that, you are having your rows in which some are with empty columns and you want to replace empty columns results with any character?

Comment: UPDATE table SET field = "§" WHERE field = ""

Comment: DON'T do this update. It will work only for the current data. What would happen if someone actually enters "§" in - you wouldn't be able to see the difference.

Comment: Just search for empty columns like in `where mycolumn = ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you probably don't have empty rows but empty column values in the rows. Wouldn't it be better if you just do it like `if (!empty($row['column']))` instead of trying to put some bogus character?

Or if you want to do a SELECT just do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name > ''; // seems to work for both NULL and empty string
```

Or:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE column_name IS NULL or column_name = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE `table` SET column = "§" WHERE column = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's bad to add character to an empty column because you are only adding extra size to the database. It's easy to search empty string on the database. Possible solutions of searching will be using of `IS NULL` to search for `null` columns.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE collName IS NULL
```

Another is by using `CHAR_LENGTH` (*which gets the length of the data in the column*)

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(collName) = 0
```

or by simply comparing it to `''`

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE colName = ''
```